# javascript append odd output

Tags: javascript, asp.net-ajax

I have some JavaScript AJAX function that is supposed to rewrite a section of my page when something happens. It works great...  except that what I tell it to write to the section isn't always what winds up on the page.

For example: this bit of code outputs what I would expect, a dropdownlist with one item in it.

```
function(response) {
    $('#serverSelection').html('');
    $('#serverSelection').append('<div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-md-2" for="ServerList">Assign the Sentinel to a Server</label><span class=" col-md-10"><select class="form-control" id="SentinelServerId" name="SentinelServerId"><option value="Contact">Contact</option>');        
    $('#serverSelection').append('</select></span></div>');
}
```

and the expected output

```
<span class="form-group" id="serverSelection">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="ServerList">Assign the Sentinel to a Server</label>
        <span class=" col-md-10">
            <select name="SentinelServerId" class="form-control" id="SentinelServerId">
                <option value="Contact">Contact</option>
            </select>
        </span>
    </div>
</span>
```

Nice. The < option > is nicely nested inside the < select >.

But this code produces something different, even tho all I did was move the < option > element from the end of the 3rd line to its own .append() on the 4th line.

```
function(response) {
    $('#serverSelection').html('');
    $('#serverSelection').append('<div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-md-2" for="ServerList">Assign the Sentinel to a Server</label><span class=" col-md-10"><select class="form-control" id="SentinelServerId" name="SentinelServerId">');
    $('#serverSelection').append('<option value="Contact">Contact</option>');
    $('#serverSelection').append('</select></span></div>');
}
```

and this is what it produces.  I really expected to be exactly the same as the first (correct) output.

```
<span class="form-group" id="serverSelection">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="ServerList">Assign the Sentinel to a Server</label>
        <span class=" col-md-10">
            <select name="SentinelServerId" class="form-control" id="SentinelServerId"></select>
        </span>
    </div>
    <option value="Contact">Contact</option>
</span>
```

How did the Contact option wind up outside of the < select >, the < span >, and the < div >? Or is something doing me a 'favor' by closing out my open elements when I get to the end of line 3 even tho I am not done adding stuff inside of those elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because jQuery automatically appends end tags during each call to `append`.

The better way to do this, both to prevent this issue and in terms of efficiency, is to create the entire html string you want to add, then append them all at once.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xc2hpwa2/

E.g.:

```
function (response){
    var html = '';
    html += '<div class="form-group"><label class="control-label col-md-2" for="ServerList">Assign the Sentinel to a Server</label><span class=" col-md-10"><select class="form-control" id="SentinelServerId" name="SentinelServerId">';

    html +='<option value="Contact">Contact</option>';

    html += '</select></span></div>';

    $('#serverSelection').html(html);
}
```